# How to calculate progressBar to start from 0 to 100 percentages in specific given time?

Tags: c#, winforms

This timer settings make it loading the progressBar from 0 to 100 in 4 seconds.
but I don't understand the calculation.  if the interval is 30ms and the checking is in the tick event is if waitingTime increasing higher then 35 then 4 seconds passed.

but 30 * 35 is 1050

The main goal is while it's loading the map in the  chromiumwebbrowser to show a progressBar  indicating the time left to load the map. but the map is loading too fast for sure after the next time i open it so the progressBar almost can't be see. that's why I want to make some kind of faking loading of the map but with the time it's taking to load the map.

the same idea in general of splash screen I think.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Weather
{
    public partial class GoogleMapsForm : Form
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer loadingMapTimer;

        public GoogleMapsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            loadingMapTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            loadingMapTimer.Interval = 30;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            loadingMapTimer.Tick += LoadingMapTimer_Tick;

            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadingStateChanged += ChromiumWebBrowser1_LoadingStateChanged;
            chromiumWebBrowser1.Load("D:\\Csharp Projects\\Weather\\map.html");
        }

        int waitingTime = 0;
        private void LoadingMapTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (progressBar1.Value < 100)
            {
                progressBar1.Value++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (waitingTime++ > 35)
                {
                    progressBar1.Visible = false;
                    chromiumWebBrowser1.Visible = true;
                }
            }
        }

        bool startTimerOnce = true;
        private void ChromiumWebBrowser1_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, CefSharp.LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                if (e.IsLoading)
                {
                    chromiumWebBrowser1.Visible = false;
                    if (startTimerOnce)
                    {
                        loadingMapTimer.Enabled = true;
                        startTimerOnce = false;
                    }
                    progressBar1.Visible = true;
                }
            }));
        }

        private void GoogleMapsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why 100? You can change the maxinum value of the progressbar to 134.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post says that you want to increment 100 values in 4 seconds. Consider 'not' using a `Timer` for this. Here's one alternative way to go about it:

- Set how frequently you want the progress bar to update (let's say `UPDATE_RESOLUTION` = 25 ms). This doesn't affect the *value* of the progress bar, however.
- Loop, updating at `UPDATE_RESOLUTION` intervals.
- Use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to keep track of elapsed time.
- To **calculate progress bar** set `Value` to the fraction of `StopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` / 0.04 where `progressBar1.Maximum` is 100
- Exit the loop when `StopWatch.Elapsed` exceeds 4 seconds.

---

```
public partial class GoogleMapsForm : Form
{
    public GoogleMapsForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        chromiumWebBrowser1.LoadingStateChanged += onLoadingStateChanged;
        chromiumWebBrowser1.Load("https://www.google.com");
    }
    private async void onLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        const int UPDATE_RESOLUTION =25;
        if(e.IsLoading)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> progressBar1.Visible= true));                
            sw.Start();
            while(sw.Elapsed <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4))
            {
                await Task.Delay(UPDATE_RESOLUTION);
                if (!IsDisposed)
                {
                    BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                        var progress = Math.Min(100, (int)Math.Round(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds / 0.04));
                        progressBar1.Value = progress;
                    }));
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progressBar1.Visible = false));

            Debug.WriteLine($"Progress: {progressBar1.Value} Elapsed {sw.Elapsed.ToString(@"ss\:ff")}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]